# How to detect errors in NuGet pack within a Jenkins build?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, nuget

I am using *nuget.exe pack* to build NuGet packages on a Jenkins server from a Powershell script:

```
& "C:\Git\packages\nuget.exe" pack -Build -ForceEnglishOutput -Prop Configuration=Release -IncludeReferencedProjects -OutputDirectory "c:\git\Packages" -Verbosity quiet
```

This will compile the csproj in the current folder and place the compiled .nupkg into the 'c:\git\packages' folder. However if the build fails how can I tell Jenkins that it failed? In Jenkins I execute the above script via 'Execute Windows batch command':

```
powershell -File Pack.ps1
```

It has a property for ERRORLEVEL to set build unstable, but how do I set this in my powershell script? I can't find any documentation on nuget.exe regarding this :( Currently if the build fails Jenkins carries on regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as easy as adding

```
Exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

to the end of your powershell script.

See more on returning error codes here https://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/returning-error-code-on-scripts-how-to.html